# ANTLR4 c++ target getLine()/getCharPositioninLine() in visitor

Tags: antlr4, c++17

What is the recommended way to get line/position data in a visitor? There's no way to get from a context to a token (at least there are no functions in the class definitions to allow this) so what is the recommended way to do so from contexts?

Using antlr4 and c++17

-- UPDATE --

Thanks Mike for pointing me in the right direction and prompt response. So here's my solution:

ctx->ID()->getSymbol()->getLine() or ->getCharPositionInLine()

where ID is the name of one of the TerminalNodes (one of your lexer rule names that can be in your context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both a terminal node as well as a parser context have token members which carry position information. For a parser context this is the start and end node of the range for which it applies. See the [token implementation](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/Token.h#L60) of the C++ target.

Comment: Yes, I saw the token.h code. I just don't know how to get the token from the visitor as all of the generated contexts are rejecting ctx->getToken() and ctx->token() as they don't have them as member functions. Also, The TerminalNodes only have parents and getSymbol().

Comment: However, how would you get a token directly from the context? In the antlr generated parser there are no member functions that return token in any of the contexts.

Comment: You have to cast. If the context is a parser context cast to it and get start and stop tokens from that. If it is a terminal node cast to that and get the token fromt he `getSymbol()` function.